# Which licence and format should I use for the Norwegian language "data" I am creating?

Tags: language, licensing, csv

While learning a foreign language, I am creating my own list of verbs (with their variants when conjugated), list of idioms, nouns (with plural form), etc.

As an example, let's focus on the verbs: I have them in a CSV file and I upload the updates to http://ankisrs.net from time to time. I had to create this list because most of the ones I am finding on the web or in books are incomplete.

I would like to put all the lists I have collected online but I am wondering if **another format than CSV would make sense** and **what kind of licence should I attach to it** (or no licence at all)?

Comment: Thomas, your question is somewhat vague. If you don't require attribution, then I would license them as CC0 (public domain). If each data item has just a few columns, then CSV format would easiest for others to use.

Comment: @Andrew-OpenGeoCode if you add this as an answer, i'll delete mine and add it as a comment

Comment: @albert - I'm ok as a comment. This is more of an opinion than a solution.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. I think the attribution part deserves a question on its own (should I mention my colleagues for each new verb they taught me for instance?). But again, I may be wrong because all of this is new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

andrew's option for cc0 is spot on, if that is your case.
as far as formats go, json is ideal in my opinion, especially for web. but csv is just fine. if you want to join team open, go ahead and convert it to open data format (odf) too, which helps encourage others to use .odf and open office.

Comment: For those that are programming proficient, JSON is the most common format for exchanging data. RDF and Linked Data would be the other alternatives.

Comment: CSV is the standard for word lists exchanges, especially in the Anki SRS world.

Comment: json-ld just for the best of both worlds

Comment: I expect that people interested by these data will not to be programming efficient. Something is telling me that CSV will be a good choice because it can be opened in Excel / Open Office and it is somewhat easy to convert it in any another format.

Comment: can't argue, but i'm also of the opinion a code-literate population is just around the corner